# Why do npm modules, like material-ui, export es6 and es5 files?

Tags: javascript, material-ui

In many npm modules I recently installed (eg. @material-ui/core) there are three ways to import the same React component:

```
import { AppBar } from '@material-ui/core'
import AppBar from '@material-ui/core/AppBar/AppBar'
import AppBar from '@material-ui/core/es/AppBar/AppBar'
```

1. In which scenario should I use variant 3 / es6 exported files?
2. If `tree-shaking` / `dead code elimination` works in webpack and the npm module. Should I rather use variant 1 (named import) instead of variant 2 (default export)?

Answer (score 0):

There are two types of export:

1) Named export that is you export something like:

```
// exports a function declared earlier
export { myFunction }; 

// exports a constant
export const FOO = "foo";
```

if you want to import these, then syntax would be like:

```
import {FOO, myFunction} from './file';
```

2) Default export that is you export something like:

```
export default function() {}
```

you can rename your function, class to any name you want when you import, and its syntax would be like:

```
import myFunction from './file';
```

NOTE: You can have multiple named export in single file but you can not have multiple default export in single file.

For more detail check out this link: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/web/javascript/reference/statements/export

Comment: On your first example I wouldn't do `export { myFunction };`, although it is correct, it seams a bit confusing; that you're exporting an object that has a function in it.. Instead, do `export function myFunction() {...}` Don't you think this is more clear?

Answer (score 0):

The main difference is how that library is exporting the modules.

When you do `import AppBar from '@material-ui/core/AppBar/AppBar'`, this means that `@material-ui/core/AppBar/AppBar` is exporting a single `object` with `export default AppBar`.

> And you're expected to imported as you did. However you're not limited to export a single default export from your module.

For example with `React` exposes the main object (i.e. `React` which is again being exported as default) that has all the properties you may want to use. But with the import syntax from ES6, you  can import a specific property/function from that module(e.g. `import { Component } from 'react';` which is exported as `export class Component...`)

I hope that's clear!